# npm config delete <setting> is deleting my .npmrc file

Tags: node.js, npm

If I create an .npmrc file by:

```
touch /Users/$USER/.npmrc
```

and do an:

```
ls -a
npm config set proxy ${proxy_url}
```

I can see my proxy set in my .npmrc file. However, if I switch networks and I want to delete it, I tried:

```
npm config delete proxy
```

And when I do an:

ls -a

My entire .npmrc file appears to have been deleted, which is giving me an

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, unlink...
```

Can anyone help? I just want to delete that setting in my .npmrc file, not delete the entire file.

Comment: are you setting any other values? If its the only value, then deleting it should be the same as not having a file.

Comment: But that deletes the entire file then?

Comment: I cant say for certain (you're free to test for yourself). But there'd be no reason not to delete the file. It is the same config as not having the file.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases,  when you **manually create** the .npmrc :

```
touch .npmrc
```

it may not work

**Instead:**
Always edit the .npmrc file created automatically using an IDE 
**OR** use npm commands like `npm config ...`to change the configurations.

(For now, delete the file you created, run a config command to create the .npmrc again)

*Additional info*: `npm config ls -l` is a useful command to see information about the npm settings and path location of your .npmrc.

---